# What function should I use to change image using left and right arrow keys

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a gallery. of images, I need to change the image when the user will press the arrow keys after the modal popup. left arrow key to change the image to the left and the right arrow key for right. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so I couldn't understand what function should I use to change the images to left and right.

I tried

```css
.modal {
  width: 58%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 22, 0.5);
  margin-left: 300px;
  max-width: 779px;
  min-width: 779px;
}

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: -10%;
}

.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: -149px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  left: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <p align="center"><img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" width="250" height="164" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x200" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <div class="mySlides">
          <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/collection/190727/300x210" style="width: 98%;
position: relative;
left: 10px;
top: 109px;">
        </div>
        <a class="prev" id="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 37) {} else if (e.keyCode === 39) {}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

- You could create an array of all the images you wanted to cycle through.
- Then create a `count` variable to index this array, using the [`remainder operator (%)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to keep it within range.

**This is what that would look like:** (Use <kbd>leftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>rightArrow</kbd> to cycle)

```js
const imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
const images = ['https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.PhOSiFj5bJt_uNbE7uw18QHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.qazsMQBX3pgWM7efm52WGwHaE7%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.M1ZwTSJXeW4021AafDtf9gHaE7%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.Wmr6TCnknZHO2DPszEf2bwHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.TRm_imdlOXbV4bggHxIcuwHaDt%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse3.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.0_abpwaxZ_xpc0V8kVZWMwHaLI%26pid%3DApi&f=1', 'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.PPTPdfKia0RZBpC91MOG5wHaHa%26pid%3DApi&f=1'];

let current = 700;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
  if (e.code === "ArrowRight") current++
  else if (e.code == "ArrowLeft") current--
  imageElement.src = images[current % images.length];
  e.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.PhOSiFj5bJt_uNbE7uw18QHaEK%26pid%3DApi&f=1">
```

Note: [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is deprecated. So I swapped it out for [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Fix negative modulo
const mod = (n, m) => ((n % m) + m) % m;

let isModalOpen = true; // You need to toggle this on modal open.
                        // use a Modal Object singleton,
                        // or a Modal Class, whatever.

const images = [
  "src 0",
  "src 1",
  "src 2",
]; // images by group of images. 

const tot = images.length; // image length depend on how many images-by-group.  
                           // You currently don't have any grouping. 
                           // You need to implement that.
                           
let idx = 0; // Depends on the clicked thumbnail index.
             // might be: 1, 2, 0, - anything.
             // It's on you to implement that!
             // PS: The index can only depend on the index-by-images-group.
             // And you're missing that galleries groups BTW. 
             // But that's also on you to figure out how to do it.   

document.addEventListener("keydown", evt => {
  const arrow = evt.key.match(/(?<=^Arrow)Right|Left/)?.[0];
  
  // First make sure #modal is open, and it's an arrow key that's pressed.
  if (!isModalOpen || !arrow) return; // Do nothing
  
  // ALL OK! Slideshow time!
  evt.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser default behavior (i.e: scrolling) 
  
  // Increment or decrement idx depending on the arrow key 
  idx += {Left: () => -1, Right: () => +1}[arrow]();
  
  // Fix/Loop index
  idx = mod(idx, tot);
  
  // Get the image src to show!
  const src = images[idx];
  
  // Test:
  console.log(src)
  
  
});
```

```html
Click here and use arrow keys
```

Comment: Figured it out. It was just simple code. Thnx for the help anyway.                                                             document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) 
{
if (e.keyCode === 37) {
  document.getElementById("prev1").click()
} else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
  document.getElementById("next1").click()
}
    });